# Is there a way to iterate only over keys of an array that contain a specific pattern

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Let's say we have an array:

```
declare -A arr
arr["1 abc"]=
arr["2 abc"]=
arr["1 xyz"]=
```

How can I go about iterating only over the elements with `abc` in the key?

Regular `for v in "${!arr[@]}"` obviously iterates over all of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` doesn't provide anything; you'll have to do the filtering in the loop.

```
for v in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    [[ $v != *abc* ]] && continue
    ...
done
```